# Hover effect on li element not working correctly in google chrome

Tags: html, css

Hey I have the problem that my hover effect doesn't work properly in google chrome. See GIF:https://giphy.com/gifs/GsUXBgcokM96zmlQkj. It works in Firefox. Can someone help me to get it running on Chrome? I think the problem lies in my CSS of #flat (js is not important here).

CodePen: https://codepen.io/NesR0M/pen/KKMzvjO.

```js
var clicked = true;

function flattoZero(){
    document.getElementById("flat").style.top = "0%";
    document.getElementById("flat").style.left = "0%";
}

function flattotheRight(){
    document.getElementById("flat").style.top = "1%";
    document.getElementById("flat").style.left = "1%";
}

function flattotheLeft(){
    document.getElementById("flat").style.top = "1%";
    document.getElementById("flat").style.left = "-1%";
}




function burgerclick() {
    const card = document.getElementById("flipable");
    card.classList.toggle("flip-card-inner-active");

    flattoZero();
    setTimeout(function(){ flattotheLeft(); }, 500);
    clicked = false;
}

function clickback() {
    const card = document.getElementById("flipable");
    card.classList.toggle("flip-card-inner-active");

    flattoZero();
    setTimeout(function(){ flattotheRight(); }, 500);
    clicked = true;
}





function mouseOver() {
    if(clicked){
    flattoZero();
    }
}
  
function mouseOut() {
    if(clicked){
        flattotheRight();
    }
}

function mouseOverflipped() {
    if(!clicked){
    flattoZero();
    }
}
  
function mouseOutflipped() {
    if(!clicked){
    flattotheLeft();
    }
}
```

```css
:root {

        /*
    --font-color: rgb(255, 238, 232);
    --flat-color: rgb(255, 114, 67);
    --main-background-color:rgb(255, 213, 197);
    */

    /*
    --font-colorF: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    --flat-colorF: rgb(255, 242, 67);
    --main-background-colorF:rgb(42, 42, 44);
    */


    --font-colorF: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    --flat-colorF: rgb(67, 170, 255);
    --main-background-colorF:rgb(42, 42, 44);
    
    --font-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    --font-hover-color: white;
    --font-underline-color: white;
    --nav-font-color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
    --burger-color: var(--font-color);
    --shadow-color: rgba(58, 58, 58, 0.2);
    --main-background-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    
}
body{   
/*Futura PT Light*/
font-family: futura-pt, sans-serif;
font-weight: 600;
font-style: italic;

color: var(--font-colorF);
background-color: var(--main-background-colorF);

width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
margin: 0px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;

transition: all 400ms ease-out;
 
}


#desktop{
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

.leftcenter {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 12vmin;
    top: 50%;
    left: 29%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: 0.30s;
}

.rightcenter {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 12vmin;
    top: 50%;
    left: 75%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: 0.30s;
}

.burger{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left: 2.5%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div{
    height: 4px;
    background-color: var(--burger-color);
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.line1{
    width: 36px;
}

.line2{
    width: 24px;
}

.line3{
    width: 30px;
}

.burger:hover div{
    width: 36px;
}

.nav{
    list-style-type:none;
    font-size: 6vmin;
    font-weight: 500;
}


.flip-card {
    perspective: 10000px;  
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
  
.flip-card-inner {
    position: relative;
    height: 80%;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 162vh;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.flip-card-inner-active {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari */
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.flip-card-front {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    
}
  
.flip-card-back {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: var(--font-color);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}



ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    list-style-type: none;
    align-items: start;
    justify-content: space-between;
}


ul li {
    padding: 6px 0;
}

ul li p {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 4px 0;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 4vh;
    color: var(--nav-font-color);
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: 0.5s;

    
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 4vh;
    text-transform: lowercase;
}

ul li p::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    background: var(--font-underline-color);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: right;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}

ul li p:hover {
    color: var(--font-hover-color);
}

ul li p:hover::after {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: left;
}

#flat{
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;  
        top: 1%;
        left: 1%;
        background-color: var(--flat-colorF);
        z-index: -5;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }

@media screen and (max-width: 100vh){
    .leftcenter {
        font-size: 6vmin;
        top: 8.2%;
        left: 62%;
    }
    .rightcenter{
        font-size: 6vmin;
        top: 8.2%;
        left: 85%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner" id="flipable">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <img id="desktop" src="img/_1080374.jpg" alt="Picture">
      <div class="leftcenter">NAME</div>
      <div class="rightcenter">NAME</div>
      <div class="burger" onclick="burgerclick()" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()">
          <div class="line1"></div>
          <div class="line2"></div>
          <div class="line3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <ul>
        <li><p id="home" onclick="clickback()" onmouseover="mouseOverflipped()" onmouseout="mouseOutflipped()">BACK</p></li>
        <li><p>ABOUT ME</p></li>
        <li><p>PROJECTS</p></li>
        <li><p>CONTACT</p></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="flat"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the front of the card gets in front of the back of the card even after the rotation, just the left part (that's why you can hover in the right part). A quick fix is to add a little space between both faces with `translate3d(0, 0, 1px)` in the `.flip-card-back` element:

```js
var clicked = true;

function flattoZero(){
    document.getElementById("flat").style.top = "0%";
    document.getElementById("flat").style.left = "0%";
}

function flattotheRight(){
    document.getElementById("flat").style.top = "1%";
    document.getElementById("flat").style.left = "1%";
}

function flattotheLeft(){
    document.getElementById("flat").style.top = "1%";
    document.getElementById("flat").style.left = "-1%";
}




function burgerclick() {
    const card = document.getElementById("flipable");
    card.classList.toggle("flip-card-inner-active");

    flattoZero();
    setTimeout(function(){ flattotheLeft(); }, 500);
    clicked = false;
}

function clickback() {
    const card = document.getElementById("flipable");
    card.classList.toggle("flip-card-inner-active");

    flattoZero();
    setTimeout(function(){ flattotheRight(); }, 500);
    clicked = true;
}





function mouseOver() {
    if(clicked){
    flattoZero();
    }
}
  
function mouseOut() {
    if(clicked){
        flattotheRight();
    }
}

function mouseOverflipped() {
    if(!clicked){
    flattoZero();
    }
}
  
function mouseOutflipped() {
    if(!clicked){
    flattotheLeft();
    }
}
```

```css
:root {

        /*
    --font-color: rgb(255, 238, 232);
    --flat-color: rgb(255, 114, 67);
    --main-background-color:rgb(255, 213, 197);
    */

    /*
    --font-colorF: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    --flat-colorF: rgb(255, 242, 67);
    --main-background-colorF:rgb(42, 42, 44);
    */


    --font-colorF: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    --flat-colorF: rgb(67, 170, 255);
    --main-background-colorF:rgb(42, 42, 44);
    
    --font-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    --font-hover-color: white;
    --font-underline-color: white;
    --nav-font-color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
    --burger-color: var(--font-color);
    --shadow-color: rgba(58, 58, 58, 0.2);
    --main-background-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    
}
body{   
/*Futura PT Light*/
font-family: futura-pt, sans-serif;
font-weight: 600;
font-style: italic;

color: var(--font-colorF);
background-color: var(--main-background-colorF);

width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
margin: 0px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;

transition: all 400ms ease-out;
 
}


#desktop{
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

.leftcenter {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 12vmin;
    top: 50%;
    left: 29%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: 0.30s;
}

.rightcenter {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 12vmin;
    top: 50%;
    left: 75%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: 0.30s;
}

.burger{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left: 2.5%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div{
    height: 4px;
    background-color: var(--burger-color);
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.line1{
    width: 36px;
}

.line2{
    width: 24px;
}

.line3{
    width: 30px;
}

.burger:hover div{
    width: 36px;
}

.nav{
    list-style-type:none;
    font-size: 6vmin;
    font-weight: 500;
}


.flip-card {
    perspective: 10000px;  
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
  
.flip-card-inner {
    position: relative;
    height: 80%;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 162vh;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.flip-card-inner-active {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari */
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.flip-card-front {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    
}
  
.flip-card-back {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: var(--font-color);
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translate3d(0, 0, 1px);
}



ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    list-style-type: none;
    align-items: start;
    justify-content: space-between;
}


ul li {
    padding: 6px 0;
}

ul li p {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 4px 0;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 4vh;
    color: var(--nav-font-color);
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: 0.5s;

    
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 4vh;
    text-transform: lowercase;
}

ul li p::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    background: var(--font-underline-color);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: right;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}

ul li p:hover {
    color: var(--font-hover-color);
}

ul li p:hover::after {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: left;
}

#flat{
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;  
        top: 1%;
        left: 1%;
        background-color: var(--flat-colorF);
        z-index: -5;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }

@media screen and (max-width: 100vh){
    .leftcenter {
        font-size: 6vmin;
        top: 8.2%;
        left: 62%;
    }
    .rightcenter{
        font-size: 6vmin;
        top: 8.2%;
        left: 85%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner" id="flipable">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <img id="desktop" src="img/_1080374.jpg" alt="Picture">
      <div class="leftcenter">NAME</div>
      <div class="rightcenter">NAME</div>
      <div class="burger" onclick="burgerclick()" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()">
          <div class="line1"></div>
          <div class="line2"></div>
          <div class="line3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <ul>
        <li><p id="home" onclick="clickback()" onmouseover="mouseOverflipped()" onmouseout="mouseOutflipped()">BACK</p></li>
        <li><p>ABOUT ME</p></li>
        <li><p>PROJECTS</p></li>
        <li><p>CONTACT</p></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="flat"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```